# Preload first frame of video using react native video so user won't have to wait while playing

Tags: react-native, preload, react-native-video

In my app i've list of videos like instagram and what i want to is to preload first frame of video so when user opens app they don't have to wait until it load.
I am using **react-native-video**. I can not cached video because its utilising too much memory and getting crash.
Any help/suggestion appreciated.

Comment: you can use `poster` prop, value is image url to show while video is loading https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#poster

Comment: @VáclavRyska same implementation is already there but client's requirement is that when user click on full-screen mode for video then it should start immediately, that's why I need to preload the first frame

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffmpeg-kit to generate the video frame and then render.